# Display dropdown-menu near hamburger icon when it appears

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar, hamburger-menu

How can I display correctly one existing dropdown-menu near hamburger-menu when it appears?

I tried to find this way, but no success. Can not correctly move it out! Also did not find some examples to do it. To make a new dropdown-menu and hide another is not a problem, but to move this one near hamburger-menu correctly is not so easy. For me, ofcorse :)

But I think after that there will be some other problems. Overlap each other and so on...

Maybe really choose the easiest way and make new one?

Anyway, maybe someone wiser can help and do it if there is nothing to do :)

Maybe for somebody else will be useful...

Here is [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGeUf.jpg) how I have imagined

Here is **[`LIVE DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/4p3xrksh/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="display:inline-block;float:right;position:relative;right:70px;">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Second <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Second-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"          aria-expanded="false" style="right:-60px;">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
        
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Second <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Second-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Fifth <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Fifth-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fifth-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fifth-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

This alignment will be ok as long as button is displayed a better behavior of the dropdown, when click it you could change the  width property.

Comment: Thank you for your dedication, but that is not what I wanted!

I wanted to find another way- just somehow move it using css!